# Dynamic videos from user inputs - How does it work?

Tags: image, video, html5-video, video-processing

**Is there a way to *generate* a video frame's content by code?**

For example :
 
I want to make a program that takes some `string` variable as input and then gives an output video of same text but now with special effects on the text itself.

It came to my mind the idea after seeing some projects that Facebook has done in their website. They have a database of pictures, comments, friends, events, likes and so on, that are related to a User. With all this information they do videos like for example *Friend's day*, a video that is completely related to the user that wants to post it.

**How does these things work?** 
Is there some sort of software I can use? Can someone give me a place to start with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to make a program that takes some string variable as input and then gives an output video of same text but now with special effects on the text itself.

You can render the text using canvas and record the result using the new [Media Recorder API](https://devdocs.io/dom/mediarecorder).

The effects can be made various ways of course, and the text content itself can be used against a database, or in conjunction with machine learning to structure/obtain some data relative to the text. This has a wide scope though, wider than what fits in here.

In any case, the generation of the video itself is shown below. It is a simple example where you can enter some text, it gets animated and recorded as video. When you click stop the actual video will show instead (which you can allow user to download). You can extend with other effects, storyboard features so you can record scenes and develop it to make an entire movie.

Do notice that all animation happens on the canvas in real-time. Typical video is recorded at 30 frames per second and not 60 frames per second, which is the typical frame rate for canvas. This is also something to consider in regard to smoothness. However, you can use this to your advantage by targeting 30 FPS to give your code a little more time to process. The API is suppose to support step-recording by not giving a frame rate as argument, but I have not been able to make this work as of yet.

There are currently limits with support of the API as not all browsers supports it yet.

## Example

```js
// un-refined code for demo use only
// set up globals, get key elements
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var txt = document.querySelector("input");
var c = document.querySelector("canvas");

// make 2d context without alpha channel
var ctx = c.getContext("2d", {alpha: false});
var isRecording = false;

// stream vars
var rec, stream, tref;

// if clicked, lets go
btn.onclick = setup;

function setup() {
  
  // toggle button text/status for demo
  if (isRecording) {
    this.disabled = true;
    this.innerHTML = "Making video...";
    stop();
    return
  }
  else {
    isRecording = true;
    this.innerHTML = "Click to stop & show video";
  }
  
  // Setup canvas for text rendering
  var ct1 = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ct2 = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctxText1 = ct1.getContext("2d");
  var ctxText2 = ct2.getContext("2d");
  var w, h;
  
  w = ct1.width = ct2.width = c.width;
  h = ct1.height = ct2.height = c.height;
  
  setupCtx(ctxText1, "#333", "#FF9F05");
  setupCtx(ctxText2, "#FF9F05", "#000");
  
  function setupCtx(ctxText, bg, fg) {
    ctxText.textAlign = "center";
    ctxText.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctxText.font = "92px sans-serif";
    ctxText.fillStyle = bg;
    ctxText.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctxText.fillStyle = fg;
    ctxText.translate(w/2, h/2);
    ctxText.rotate(-0.5);
    ctxText.fillText(txt.value.toUpperCase(), 0, 0);
  }
  
  // populate grid (see Square object below which handles the tiles)
  var cols = 18,rows = 11,
      cellWidth = (c.width / cols)|0,
      cellHeight = (c.height / rows)|0,
      grid = [],
      len = cols * rows, y = 0, x,
      index, hasActive = true;

  for (; y < rows; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
      grid.push(new Square(ctx, x * cellWidth, y * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight, ct1, ct2, 0.01));
    }
  }

  x = 0;

  // start recording canvas to video
  record();
  
  //animation loop (refactor at will)
  function loop() {
    
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    // trigger cells
    for (y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        var gx = (x | 0) - y;
        if (gx >= 0 && gx < cols) {
            index = y * cols + gx;
            grid[index].trigger();
        }
    }

    x += 0.25;

    // update all
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) grid[i].update();
    tref = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }

  // setup media recorder to record canvas @ 30 FPS (note: canvas = 60 FPS by def.)
  function record() {
    stream = c.captureStream(30);
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    rec.addEventListener('dataavailable', done);
    rec.start();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
}

// stop recorder and trigger dataavailable event
function stop() {
  rec.stop();
  cancelAnimationFrame(tref);  // stop loop as well
}

// finish up, show new shiny video instead of canvas
function done(e) {
  var blob = new Blob([e.data], {"type": "video/webm"});
  var video = document.createElement("video");
 
  document.body.removeChild(c);
  document.body.appendChild(video);
  
  // play, Don
  video.autoplay = video.loop = video.controls = true;
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  video.onplay = function() {
    div.innerHTML = "Playing resulting video below:";
  };
}

// stolen from a previous example I made (CC3.0-attr btw as always)
// this is included for the sole purpose of some animation.
function Square(ctx, x, y, w, h, image, image2, speed) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.height = h;
  this.width = w;
  this.image = image;
  this.image2 = image2;
  this.first = true;
  this.alpha = 0;          // current alpha for this instance
  this.speed = speed;      // increment for alpha per frame
  this.triggered = false;  // is running
  this.done = false;       // has finished
}

Square.prototype = {
    trigger: function () { // start this rectangle
        this.triggered = true
    },
    update: function () {
        if (this.triggered && !this.done) { // only if active
            this.alpha += this.speed; // update alpha
            if (this.alpha <= 0 || this.alpha >= 1) 
                this.speed = -this.speed;
        }
        var t = Math.sin(Math.PI * this.alpha);
        if (t <= 0) this.first = !this.first;

        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color; // render this instance
        this.ctx.globalAlpha = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, t));

        var cx = this.x + this.width * 0.5, // center position
            cy = this.y + this.width * 0.5;

        this.ctx.setTransform(t*0.5+0.5, 0, 0, t*0.5+0.5, cx, cy); // scale and translate
        this.ctx.rotate(-Math.PI * (1 - t)); // rotate, 90° <- alpha
        this.ctx.translate(-cx, -cy); // translate back
        this.ctx.drawImage(this.first ? this.image : this.image2, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
};
```

```css
body {background: #555;color:#ddd;font:16px sans-serif}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Enter text to animate: <input value="U R AWESOME"></label> 
  <button>Click to start animation + recording</button>
</div>
<canvas width=640 height=400></canvas>
```